# model.matrix from lists in r

Tags: r, model.matrix

I am trying to convert list of factors to matrix for example:

myLists:

```
    [[1]]
    [1] "RA"   "FZFG" "BR"  
    [[2]]
    [1] "RA"
    [[3]]
    [1] ""
    [[4]]
    [1] ""
```

to

```
RA  FZFG  BR
1    1    1
1    0    0
0    0    0
0    0    0
```

I tried to do the following:

```
allFactors<-c("RA","FZFG","BR")
mat<-model.matrix(~allFactors,  data =myLists)
```

but have ths error:

> Error in data.frame(c("RA", "FZFG", "BR"), "RA", "", "", "", "",
>   c("RA",  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 1, 2, 4, 5,
>   7, 6, 8, 9

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(myLists)[-1]
```

Or using `base R`

```
 table(stack(setNames(myLists, seq_along(myLists)))[2:1])[,-1]
```

Comment: Better base R solution and I have to understand mtabulate :) +1 !

Answer (score 3):

Base `R` option:

```
level = unique(unlist(lst))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(u) table(factor(u, levels=level))))
```